# How should I handle timestamps in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

Whenever I read floats from sqlite using pandas.read_sql_query, there's a chance it'll have a slight precision error. So when I search for that row later by using that unprecise float, it can't find that row.

Here's the exact process I used to recreate the problem:

1. Create row in sqlite database test table

```
insert into test values ("bc011fcd6c8e40069dd7c7f2fdf92952", 1669836415.8800698)
```

[sqlite test table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL1kP.png)

2. Read row from test table

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd
import os


def main():
    file_path = '/path/to/sqlite.db'
    conn_str = f'sqlite:///{file_path}'
    engine = sa.create_engine(conn_str)

    query = 'select * from test WHERE job_id = "bc011fcd6c8e40069dd7c7f2fdf92952" AND modified_on = 1669836415.8800698'
    data = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=engine)
    print(data['modified_on'].iloc[0])  # gives 1669836415.8800697


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm currently using this float as a timestamp to query for later.
So how should I handle this and other floats in python? Should I always round floats to 6 decimal places?

Note/interesting observations:

```
print(data['modified_on'].iloc[0]-int(data['modified_on '].iloc[0]))  # gives 0.8800697326660156
```

Comment: Don't use floats, use integers.

Comment: `insert into test values ("bc011fcd6c8e40069dd7c7f2fdf92952", datetime(1669836415.8800698, 'unixepoch'))` where `SELECT datetime(1669836415.8800698, 'unixepoch'); 2022-11-30 19:26:55` . See [Date/Time functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: What about for floats I use for calcuations, should I also always store those as integers?

Comment: Read [Floating point](https://sqlite.org/floatingpoint.html).  Or use a database that supports Numeric/Decimal natively.

Comment: In the long run, I suspect you'll be happier if you can devise some way to search for timestamps using a *range*.  Like, 1669836415.875 – 1669836415.885.  (Although, truth be told, you're getting close to the limit of double precision, here.)

Comment: Although floating-point values are "always imprecise", it turns out that for many real-world quantities, including timestamps, that's perfectly appropriate!  Your event didn't happen at *exactly* 1669836415.88; it was inevitably a few microseconds or nanoseconds or femtoseconds earlier or later than that.  You can't know *exactly* when it was, and even if you did, you couldn't represent that number anyway.  So your recorded timestamp is *always* going to be slightly off from the "real" value, so it's perfectly appropriate to use a search technique that allows for a certain amount of slop.

Comment: got it thanks, I'll probably switch to using epoch time for timestamps and keep in mind these aspects about floats.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use floats if you can avoid it, this is just how they work:

```
>>> print ("%40.18f\n" % (1669836415.8800698))
           **1669836415.880069732666015625  <<<< the actual value**

>>> print ("%40.7f\n" % (1669836415.8800698))
                      **1669836415.8800697  <<<< the rounded value**
```